# Multiply a number of columns by a specific column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame with several columns containing different areas by location. In another column I have a density value. I would like to know how to create a new table (ideally through a loop) with each area multiplied by the density. My data frame looks like:

```
X   Area1  Area2  Area3  Area4 Density
A   10.1    12     20     25    0.04
B   4.2     7.3    30     35    0.05
C   5.3     9.6    10     15    0.07
D   0.2     0.3    2      3     0.01
```

I have seem a similar question at: [Multiply many columns by a specific other column in R with data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123098/multiply-many-columns-by-a-specific-other-column-in-r-with-data-table) but cannot figure out a way to adapt it to work for my data. Many thanks :)

Comment: If `dt` is your *data.table*: `dt[, 2:5 := lapply(.SD, '*', Density), .SDcols = 2:5][]`?

Comment: @Jaap, all they need to do is make a copy, the rest is duplicate, no?

Comment: @docendodiscimus yes, but added an answer because it wasn't clear to OP apparently; I've also added a link to the standard `copy` question which makes it more complete imo

Answer (score 2):

If `dt` is your *data.table* then

```
dtcopy <- copy(dt)
dtcopy[, 2:5 := lapply(.SD, '*', Density), .SDcols = 2:5][]
```

gives the following result:

> ```
> > dtcopy
>    X Area1 Area2 Area3 Area4 Density
> 1: A 0.404 0.480  0.80  1.00    0.04
> 2: B 0.210 0.365  1.50  1.75    0.05
> 3: C 0.371 0.672  0.70  1.05    0.07
> 4: D 0.002 0.003  0.02  0.03    0.01
> ```

While your original *data.table* `dt` is still unchanged because you used the `copy`-function to make a copy:

> ```
> > dt
>    X Area1 Area2 Area3 Area4 Density
> 1: A  10.1  12.0    20    25    0.04
> 2: B   4.2   7.3    30    35    0.05
> 3: C   5.3   9.6    10    15    0.07
> 4: D   0.2   0.3     2     3    0.01
> ```

See also [Understanding exactly when a data.table is a reference to (vs a copy of) another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another) on why you need to use `copy`.

---

Used data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('X   Area1  Area2  Area3  Area4 Density
             A   10.1    12     20     25    0.04
             B   4.2     7.3    30     35    0.05
             C   5.3     9.6    10     15    0.07
             D   0.2     0.3    2      3     0.01')
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you to clarify what the .SD and .SDcols are please?

Comment: @user3489562 `.SD` (and `.SDcols`) stands for **S**ubset of **D**ata; using these concepts specifies to which columns the function has to be applied; I this case I used column positions for that, but you can also use columnnames

Comment: ok if I use what you have suggested I get the following error message: unused argument (.SDcols = 2:5)

Comment: @user3489562 Do you have `data.table` loaded? Do you have the latest version (v1.10.4)?

Comment: @Japp - I have checked and I am actually using a data frame not a data table which is probably why this isn't working. Is there a way to do it on a data frame?

Comment: @user3489562 If `df` is your dataframe: `df[2:5] <- lapply(df[2:5], '*', df$Density)`

Comment: @Japp thank you :)