# Multiply and divide many columns, by another column for each group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I've got a dataframe with the following structure:

```
# A tibble: 95 x 7
# Groups:   WallReg_2p5 [19]
   CellID_2p5 Y_Coord_2p5Weighting WallReg_2p5 piC_1  piC_2 piC_3 piC_4
        <int>                <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1       6561                0.915 African      6.55  6.63  5.84  0.766
 2       6278                0.947 African     15.1   5.59  2.15  2.01 
 3       4394                0.971 African     11.4   3.92  0.774 1.47 
 4       4840                0.994 African      4.70  0.962 6.21  3.54 
 5       4105                0.947 African      6.35  2.10  2.25  3.24 
 6       5228                1.000 Amazonian    8.49  5.00  1.92  2.42 
 7       5089                1.000 Amazonian   15.6   6.48  2.53  2.89 
 8       4939                0.998 Amazonian    5.56  2.94  0.389 2.44 
 9       5088                1.000 Amazonian   12.9   5.16  1.99  3.13 
10       4947                0.998 Amazonian    8.05 11.2   2.54  4.61 
# ... with 85 more rows
```

Here is the `dput()` of a subset of the dataframe. My real dataset consists of 10,368 rows and 255,611 columns

```
structure(list(CellID_2p5 = c(6561L, 6278L, 4394L, 4840L, 4105L, 
5228L, 5089L, 4939L, 5088L, 4947L, 1710L, 2569L, 1438L, 1175L, 
1840L, 6888L, 7185L, 6031L, 7045L, 7044L, 3432L, 3288L, 3143L, 
3574L, 3577L, 3260L, 1959L, 2568L, 2986L, 2386L, 5551L, 5407L, 
5556L, 4979L, 5694L, 5303L, 4442L, 5587L, 5157L, 4865L, 3294L, 
3009L, 2865L, 2722L, 3151L, 6427L, 6571L, 5996L, 6570L, 6139L, 
3631L, 3920L, 3342L, 3341L, 4064L, 2617L, 2049L, 3346L, 1599L, 
3205L, 7487L, 6612L, 6613L, 7630L, 7916L, 3854L, 3561L, 4290L, 
4138L, 3704L, 4211L, 4068L, 4069L, 4357L, 4648L, 5601L, 5600L, 
5455L, 5456L, 5458L, 3978L, 3822L, 3532L, 3832L, 3834L, 7105L, 
6817L, 6104L, 7963L, 6098L, 3418L, 3424L, 3281L, 3566L, 3273L
), Y_Coord_2p5Weighting = c(0.915311479119447, 0.946930129495106, 
0.971342069813261, 0.99405633822232, 0.946930129495106, 0.999762027079909, 
0.999762027079909, 0.997858923238603, 0.999762027079909, 0.997858923238603, 
0.480988768919388, 0.691513055782269, 0.402746689858737, 0.362438038283702, 
0.518773258160522, 0.876726755707508, 0.831469612302545, 0.971342069813261, 
0.854911870672947, 0.854911870672947, 0.854911870672947, 0.831469612302545, 
0.806444604267483, 0.876726755707508, 0.876726755707508, 0.831469612302545, 
0.555570233019602, 0.691513055782269, 0.779884483092882, 0.659345815100069, 
0.99405633822232, 0.997858923238603, 0.99405633822232, 0.997858923238603, 
0.988361510467761, 0.999762027079909, 0.971342069813261, 0.99405633822232, 
0.999762027079909, 0.99405633822232, 0.831469612302545, 0.779884483092882, 
0.751839807478977, 0.722363962059756, 0.806444604267483, 0.932007869282799, 
0.915311479119447, 0.971342069813261, 0.915311479119447, 0.960049854385929, 
0.896872741532688, 0.932007869282799, 0.854911870672947, 0.854911870672947, 
0.946930129495106, 0.722363962059756, 0.591309648363582, 0.854911870672947, 
0.480988768919388, 0.831469612302545, 0.779884483092882, 0.915311479119447, 
0.915311479119447, 0.751839807478977, 0.691513055782269, 0.915311479119447, 
0.876726755707508, 0.960049854385929, 0.946930129495106, 0.896872741532688, 
0.960049854385929, 0.946930129495106, 0.946930129495106, 0.971342069813261, 
0.988361510467761, 0.99405633822232, 0.99405633822232, 0.997858923238603, 
0.997858923238603, 0.997858923238603, 0.932007869282799, 0.915311479119447, 
0.876726755707508, 0.915311479119447, 0.915311479119447, 0.831469612302545, 
0.876726755707508, 0.960049854385929, 0.659345815100069, 0.960049854385929, 
0.854911870672947, 0.854911870672947, 0.831469612302545, 0.876726755707508, 
0.831469612302545), WallReg_2p5 = c("African", "African", "African", 
"African", "African", "Amazonian", "Amazonian", "Amazonian", 
"Amazonian", "Amazonian", "Arctico-Siberian", "Arctico-Siberian", 
"Arctico-Siberian", "Arctico-Siberian", "Arctico-Siberian", "Australian", 
"Australian", "Australian", "Australian", "Australian", "Chinese", 
"Chinese", "Chinese", "Chinese", "Chinese", "Eurasian", "Eurasian", 
"Eurasian", "Eurasian", "Eurasian", "Guineo-Congolian", "Guineo-Congolian", 
"Guineo-Congolian", "Guineo-Congolian", "Guineo-Congolian", "Indo-Malayan", 
"Indo-Malayan", "Indo-Malayan", "Indo-Malayan", "Indo-Malayan", 
"Japanese", "Japanese", "Japanese", "Japanese", "Japanese", "Madagascan", 
"Madagascan", "Madagascan", "Madagascan", "Madagascan", "Mexican", 
"Mexican", "Mexican", "Mexican", "Mexican", "North American", 
"North American", "North American", "North American", "North American", 
"Novozelandic", "Novozelandic", "Novozelandic", "Novozelandic", 
"Novozelandic", "Oriental", "Oriental", "Oriental", "Oriental", 
"Oriental", "Panamanian", "Panamanian", "Panamanian", "Panamanian", 
"Panamanian", "Papua-Melanesian", "Papua-Melanesian", "Papua-Melanesian", 
"Papua-Melanesian", "Papua-Melanesian", "Saharo-Arabian", "Saharo-Arabian", 
"Saharo-Arabian", "Saharo-Arabian", "Saharo-Arabian", "South American", 
"South American", "South American", "South American", "South American", 
"Tibetan", "Tibetan", "Tibetan", "Tibetan", "Tibetan"), piC_1 = c(6.54637718200684, 
15.1273813247681, 11.4171981811523, 4.70245027542114, 6.35227298736572, 
8.48885822296143, 15.5538415908813, 5.56155681610107, 12.9046697616577, 
8.04517650604248, 2.95071268081665, 21.6441345214844, 11.2329692840576, 
16.1649322509766, 17.2905006408691, 3.43583130836487, 10.0594062805176, 
12.3438568115234, 7.94222640991211, 6.89916276931763, 7.45456171035767, 
8.77329444885254, 14.3378238677979, 3.86588025093079, 12.4889860153198, 
7.18962049484253, 19.2145137786865, 22.0060653686523, 1.86285281181335, 
2.09195709228516, 9.87592029571533, 12.2629871368408, 7.31402492523193, 
0.601671099662781, 6.9998254776001, 20.6269207000732, 6.21515369415283, 
22.039529800415, 8.35955047607422, 9.50113105773926, 7.06818675994873, 
4.63532447814941, 5.81412315368652, 0.996474027633667, 8.32744407653809, 
5.03945255279541, 0.893457889556885, 2.42736291885376, 10.3842725753784, 
3.32475543022156, 8.1105375289917, 6.61336517333984, 4.06754541397095, 
3.31069254875183, 8.05746650695801, 1.24714422225952, 6.44647121429443, 
2.97141313552856, 13.3264999389648, 4.86157178878784, 6.71903085708618, 
20.3318004608154, 20.8287792205811, 10.0042209625244, 12.7859420776367, 
13.6358938217163, 15.9491415023804, 11.4823551177979, 18.6053276062012, 
16.6047229766846, 16.1496143341064, 2.9492039680481, 13.8130388259888, 
18.6300754547119, 14.464674949646, 4.92032289505005, 0.511945068836212, 
3.16324853897095, 13.3062620162964, 9.84803581237793, 1.74625515937805, 
2.54861640930176, 9.97869968414307, 11.2339553833008, 0.865878522396088, 
14.7632684707642, 21.8330593109131, 6.42118740081787, 9.51691722869873, 
13.2857227325439, 4.01672554016113, 10.9487056732178, 13.6308097839355, 
4.69979858398438, 1.83490359783173), piC_2 = c(6.62732124328613, 
5.59194660186768, 3.92186212539673, 0.962285339832306, 2.1002824306488, 
4.99801731109619, 6.4822793006897, 2.94481801986694, 5.16082000732422, 
11.2070302963257, 0.585842967033386, 4.83236265182495, 1.637331366539, 
7.65087461471558, 2.28347945213318, 7.16115474700928, 3.54162955284119, 
5.23653078079224, 2.28897953033447, 2.29887819290161, 0.752622723579407, 
0.653791189193726, 1.5378258228302, 2.15203213691711, 1.64702248573303, 
6.0682373046875, 0.22119003534317, 4.76900386810303, 0.366481363773346, 
6.11435651779175, 10.8921070098877, 7.97591733932495, 6.05282688140869, 
3.74584698677063, 5.75792741775513, 0.471727430820465, 2.75132250785828, 
1.21862363815308, 0.138835281133652, 2.98711204528809, 0.627980709075928, 
0.108154557645321, 0.995486855506897, 2.4163064956665, 0.0193456951528788, 
5.70003795623779, 5.56746625900269, 2.9861011505127, 0.344279021024704, 
0.640789806842804, 9.4457426071167, 7.05727958679199, 3.89853048324585, 
0.340702921152115, 1.17963445186615, 8.93050575256348, 14.796028137207, 
4.88054323196411, 9.28642845153809, 7.68382120132446, 2.27267980575562, 
0.916118919849396, 0.689630210399628, 0.549197673797607, 1.68408465385437, 
1.76007652282715, 3.2269868850708, 0.980833470821381, 5.00142002105713, 
3.41616177558899, 6.74930334091187, 12.0952653884888, 15.2918863296509, 
0.105648428201675, 4.59846162796021, 1.48986113071442, 5.02905178070068, 
5.07208204269409, 4.98251914978027, 4.70810985565186, 2.37468719482422, 
6.78730487823486, 6.18559217453003, 11.6090707778931, 2.91017484664917, 
3.51590204238892, 3.35987615585327, 8.74919319152832, 2.23059439659119, 
0.292922139167786, 5.41262531280518, 8.86936473846436, 8.20160961151123, 
7.33296489715576, 8.42716407775879), piC_3 = c(5.84101867675781, 
2.14856338500977, 0.774434208869934, 6.21446466445923, 2.25056719779968, 
1.9200998544693, 2.52935075759888, 0.38894659280777, 1.98762917518616, 
2.53701376914978, 6.93642854690552, 0.608367025852203, 4.7472562789917, 
1.25435817241669, 4.09390258789062, 5.41882562637329, 0.221905186772346, 
3.72868466377258, 0.763698220252991, 0.783569753170013, 8.32380294799805, 
4.482017993927, 2.38237118721008, 10.7143220901489, 10.1253957748413, 
4.51582384109497, 5.18871164321899, 1.76670265197754, 7.50785446166992, 
6.2304630279541, 8.79040622711182, 7.47595691680908, 1.57976567745209, 
1.46996772289276, 0.894773840904236, 1.30858862400055, 7.34649181365967, 
1.41060519218445, 2.03947067260742, 4.6038031578064, 4.44245910644531, 
0.236538723111153, 0.194929093122482, 0.684483885765076, 0.530747056007385, 
1.89696133136749, 1.94861626625061, 3.36041831970215, 0.0835498198866844, 
2.04665040969849, 7.02379274368286, 2.93551588058472, 5.33355855941772, 
1.59516668319702, 2.19099020957947, 2.88170146942139, 7.42911052703857, 
4.64155960083008, 2.24829292297363, 3.64715957641602, 0.363596022129059, 
1.41882479190826, 0.474381387233734, 2.24125337600708, 4.11492681503296, 
3.44695138931274, 3.08158445358276, 0.218709617853165, 2.44625425338745, 
1.71628797054291, 1.75634157657623, 4.76044988632202, 0.387977868318558, 
1.70636379718781, 1.70855867862701, 3.67641615867615, 0.744896650314331, 
1.09648311138153, 1.37377882003784, 0.200171306729317, 1.4753475189209, 
6.56762170791626, 7.72892284393311, 2.18395304679871, 0.481256455183029, 
0.37385630607605, 4.25140476226807, 6.76727914810181, 4.81376981735229, 
3.8882269859314, 2.90145373344421, 7.48540449142456, 9.90997123718262, 
4.46362543106079, 5.19004011154175), piC_4 = c(0.765519082546234, 
2.01459360122681, 1.4724348783493, 3.53503012657166, 3.23746180534363, 
2.42439723014832, 2.89345812797546, 2.43676805496216, 3.13469624519348, 
4.61154937744141, 4.51843070983887, 0.767921149730682, 5.01102733612061, 
2.94891023635864, 5.20972728729248, 1.1311411857605, 2.22004199028015, 
3.79573369026184, 0.551535904407501, 0.574182093143463, 5.87988710403442, 
5.06349992752075, 3.72144675254822, 8.49415874481201, 4.27884483337402, 
2.48057842254639, 4.45665884017944, 0.667030334472656, 6.93020153045654, 
2.26927351951599, 1.5674192905426, 3.63813829421997, 2.73822736740112, 
0.674351632595062, 1.89532685279846, 4.79139471054077, 1.34277474880219, 
0.564522683620453, 3.33897042274475, 1.42253696918488, 2.7286331653595, 
0.960368096828461, 2.00121903419495, 4.58775472640991, 2.11190366744995, 
0.29313051700592, 0.0706640183925629, 2.87113666534424, 1.36242246627808, 
3.57689785957336, 2.05132532119751, 0.340487778186798, 1.3506361246109, 
0.400035679340363, 1.65728294849396, 5.17583227157593, 6.23331356048584, 
1.60608506202698, 6.12336874008179, 0.46411395072937, 0.205161795020103, 
1.93029391765594, 2.6833176612854, 0.199026927351952, 0.0609574876725674, 
1.12770354747772, 1.49503016471863, 0.299944281578064, 0.302427768707275, 
0.745285212993622, 2.91650176048279, 4.18865776062012, 2.71514081954956, 
1.93356776237488, 1.67894613742828, 1.67655885219574, 3.09425163269043, 
2.87126135826111, 2.42724895477295, 5.48751878738403, 3.4703311920166, 
3.71456289291382, 4.29666662216187, 3.37810254096985, 3.07785415649414, 
1.90873026847839, 3.57397627830505, 0.902793109416962, 3.96058869361877, 
0.35958793759346, 2.9896719455719, 1.81924939155579, 4.22445392608643, 
2.22684979438782, 4.53710412979126)), row.names = c(NA, -95L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("CellID_2p5", "Y_Coord_2p5Weighting", 
"WallReg_2p5", "piC_1", "piC_2", "piC_3", "piC_4"), vars = "WallReg_2p5", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:4, 5:9, 10:14, 15:19, 20:24, 25:29, 30:34, 35:39, 40:44, 
    45:49, 50:54, 55:59, 60:64, 65:69, 70:74, 75:79, 80:84, 85:89, 
    90:94), group_sizes = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = structure(list(
    WallReg_2p5 = c("African", "Amazonian", "Arctico-Siberian", 
    "Australian", "Chinese", "Eurasian", "Guineo-Congolian", 
    "Indo-Malayan", "Japanese", "Madagascan", "Mexican", "North American", 
    "Novozelandic", "Oriental", "Panamanian", "Papua-Melanesian", 
    "Saharo-Arabian", "South American", "Tibetan")), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), class = "data.frame", vars = "WallReg_2p5", drop = TRUE, .Names = "WallReg_2p5"))
```

What I am trying to do is to generate weighted values of all the `piC_` columns for each region. The process for each column (`x`) involves 3 steps:

1. multiply each row in the `piC_x` column, by the values in `Y_Coord_2p5Weighting`
2. Sum the weighted `piC_x` values within each of the `WallReg_2p5` groups
3. Divide the summed `piC_x` value, by the sum of the values in `Y_Coord_2p5Weighting` for each of the `WallReg_2p5` groups

After some reading it appears that `data.table` is faster on large datasets than `dplyr`, but I am open to using either package, or even base `r`.
I have attempted to do both, but am getting incorrect results when using `data.table`, and I'm worried about the speed of `dplyr` when I apply this to my full dataframe. Here is what I've tried so far

*dplyr*

```
df <- df %>% tbl_df() %>% 
  group_by(WallReg_2p5) %>% 
  summarise(meanS = mean(piC_1), minS = min(piC_1), maxS = max(piC_1))

# A tibble: 19 x 4
   WallReg_2p5      meanS   minS  maxS
   <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 African           8.83  4.70  15.1 
 2 Amazonian        10.1   5.56  15.6 
 3 Arctico-Siberian 13.9   2.95  21.6 
 4 Australian        8.14  3.44  12.3 
 5 Chinese           9.38  3.87  14.3 
 6 Eurasian         10.5   1.86  22.0 
 7 Guineo-Congolian  7.41  0.602 12.3 
 8 Indo-Malayan     13.3   6.22  22.0 
 9 Japanese          5.37  0.996  8.33
10 Madagascan        4.41  0.893 10.4 
11 Mexican           6.03  3.31   8.11
12 North American    5.77  1.25  13.3 
13 Novozelandic     14.1   6.72  20.8 
14 Oriental         15.3  11.5   18.6 
15 Panamanian       13.2   2.95  18.6 
16 Papua-Melanesian  6.35  0.512 13.3 
17 Saharo-Arabian    5.27  0.866 11.2 
18 South American   13.2   6.42  21.8 
19 Tibetan           7.03  1.83  13.6 

weighted <- df %>%
  mutate_at(.funs = funs(.*Y_Coord_2p5Weighting), .vars = vars(starts_with("piC_"))) %>% ## multiply by lat weight
  mutate_at(.funs = funs(sum), .vars = vars(starts_with("piC_"))) %>% ## sum the weighted values
  mutate_at(.funs = funs(./sum(Y_Coord_2p5Weighting)), .vars = vars(starts_with("piC_"))) ## divide weighted values by sum of weights

weighted %>% tbl_df %>% group_by(WallReg_2p5) %>% summarise(meanS = mean(piC_1), minS = min(piC_1), maxS = max(piC_1))

# A tibble: 19 x 4
   WallReg_2p5      meanS  minS  maxS
   <chr>            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 African           8.82  8.82  8.82
 2 Amazonian        10.1  10.1  10.1 
 3 Arctico-Siberian 14.5  14.5  14.5 
 4 Australian        8.21  8.21  8.21
 5 Chinese           9.32  9.32  9.32
 6 Eurasian          9.86  9.86  9.86
 7 Guineo-Congolian  7.41  7.41  7.41
 8 Indo-Malayan     13.4  13.4  13.4 
 9 Japanese          5.47  5.47  5.47
10 Madagascan        4.38  4.38  4.38
11 Mexican           6.10  6.10  6.10
12 North American    5.09  5.09  5.09
13 Novozelandic     14.6  14.6  14.6 
14 Oriental         15.2  15.2  15.2 
15 Panamanian       13.2  13.2  13.2 
16 Papua-Melanesian  6.36  6.36  6.36
17 Saharo-Arabian    5.22  5.22  5.22
18 South American   13.2  13.2  13.2 
19 Tibetan           7.01  7.01  7.01
```

Using `dplyr` I get the correct values. However, when I use `data.table` I get incorrect values. I have based my code on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28123098/1710632), but clearly I'm doing something wrong.

*data.table*

```
df <- df %>% group_by(WallReg_2p5) %>%
  as.data.table(.) %>% setkey(., WallReg_2p5)
is.data.table(df); haskey(df)
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE

## same as above
df %>% tbl_df %>% group_by(WallReg_2p5) %>% 
  summarise(meanS = mean(piC_1), minS = min(piC_1), maxS = max(piC_1))

# A tibble: 19 x 4
   WallReg_2p5      meanS   minS  maxS
   <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 African           8.83  4.70  15.1 
 2 Amazonian        10.1   5.56  15.6 
 3 Arctico-Siberian 13.9   2.95  21.6 
 4 Australian        8.14  3.44  12.3 
 5 Chinese           9.38  3.87  14.3 
 6 Eurasian         10.5   1.86  22.0 
 7 Guineo-Congolian  7.41  0.602 12.3 
 8 Indo-Malayan     13.3   6.22  22.0 
 9 Japanese          5.37  0.996  8.33
10 Madagascan        4.41  0.893 10.4 
11 Mexican           6.03  3.31   8.11
12 North American    5.77  1.25  13.3 
13 Novozelandic     14.1   6.72  20.8 
14 Oriental         15.3  11.5   18.6 
15 Panamanian       13.2   2.95  18.6 
16 Papua-Melanesian  6.35  0.512 13.3 
17 Saharo-Arabian    5.27  0.866 11.2 
18 South American   13.2   6.42  21.8 
19 Tibetan           7.03  1.83  13.6 

# https://stackoverflow.com/q/28123098/1710632
indx <- grep("piC_", colnames(df))
for (j in indx) {
  set(df, i = NULL, j = j, value = df[[j]]*df[["Y_Coord_2p5Weighting"]]) ## multiply by weights
  set(df, i = NULL, j = j, value = sum(df[[j]])) ## sum the weighted values
  set(df, i = NULL, j = j, value = df[[j]]/sum(df[["Y_Coord_2p5Weighting"]])) ## divide by sum of weights
}
## wrong values
df %>% tbl_df %>% group_by(WallReg_2p5) %>%
  summarise(meanS = mean(piC_1), minS = min(piC_1), maxS = max(piC_1))

# A tibble: 19 x 4
   WallReg_2p5      meanS  minS  maxS
   <chr>            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 African           9.27  9.27  9.27
 2 Amazonian         9.27  9.27  9.27
 3 Arctico-Siberian  9.27  9.27  9.27
 4 Australian        9.27  9.27  9.27
 5 Chinese           9.27  9.27  9.27
 6 Eurasian          9.27  9.27  9.27
 7 Guineo-Congolian  9.27  9.27  9.27
 8 Indo-Malayan      9.27  9.27  9.27
 9 Japanese          9.27  9.27  9.27
10 Madagascan        9.27  9.27  9.27
11 Mexican           9.27  9.27  9.27
12 North American    9.27  9.27  9.27
13 Novozelandic      9.27  9.27  9.27
14 Oriental          9.27  9.27  9.27
15 Panamanian        9.27  9.27  9.27
16 Papua-Melanesian  9.27  9.27  9.27
17 Saharo-Arabian    9.27  9.27  9.27
18 South American    9.27  9.27  9.27
19 Tibetan           9.27  9.27  9.27
```

Reading `?set()`, states that it cannot perform grouping operations, but I thought that as I had already defined my groups that this process would work. I've never used `data.table` before, so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: too long and only read your 3 steps: r u looking for `df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(Y_Coord_2p5Weighting * x) / sum(Y_Coord_2p5Weighting)), by=.(WallReg_2p5), .SDcols=paste0("piC_", 1:4)]`

Comment: @chinsoon12 thanks! This is exactly what I was after. I changed it a little bit for the column selection:

`indx <- grep("piC_", colnames(df), value = TRUE); df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(Y_Coord_2p5Weighting * x) / sum(Y_Coord_2p5Weighting)), by=.(WallReg_2p5), .SDcols=indx]`