# how to round specific columns by function using R?

Tags: r, data.table, rounding, multiple-columns

I want to round off specific columns with each column have different rounding values. I tried with the following code but it gives an error:

```
roundCols <-function(repo, namcol, digiround){
  repo[,"namcol"] = round(repo[,"namcol"], digits = digiround)
  round.staus = TRUE
  return(round.staus)
}
round.staus = FALSE

ils <- config[13]$ignoreColumns
ils <- gsub("\\{|\\}", "", ils)
ils <-  ils %>% str_replace_all("\\&", ",")
coldrp <- unlist(strsplit(ils, "\\,"))
coldrp = gsub("[^a-zA-Z]+", ".", coldrp)
td <- fread(config[13]$save.location,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,drop=coldrp,blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
col_rnm <- c(names(td[,2]),names(td[,3]))  #it has 2 column who's will be round off  
col_rd <- c(2,3)    #it gives digits how much rounding off required
for (i in 1:length(col_rnm)) {
  round.staus = roundCols(td,col_rnm,col_rd[i])
}
td
```

error is :

> Error in `[.data.table`(repo, , "namcol") : 
>     column(s) not found: namcol

I tried the same given in function on a console which gives an exact result.

Expected Output:

```
Account    Chargeable.Capacity   Expected.Capacity.in.30.days    Deviation
Kishore                0.01                 0.007              3.778268e-11
```

Initially My data :

```
Account Chargeable.Capacity Expected.Capacity.in.30.days    Deviation
Kishore         0.007124108         0.007283185           3.778268e-11
```

above what is expected from the function given the code. Help me to solve that error. The effort will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a `dput` of your data to make your issue reproducible for others?

Comment: `dput` of data is here, `structure(list(Account = "Kishore", Chargeable.Capacity = 0.01, 
    Expected.Capacity.in.30.days = 0.0072831853027186, Deviation = 3.77826790758223e-11), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002571ef0>)`  .

Comment: @jay.sf this is what u said, right?

Comment: What do you want to round off to? Your `dput` is identical to your result.

Comment: I want to round off the column's value. I edited the question. I think now you can get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
for (i in 1:length(col_rnm)) {
  set(td, , col_rnm[i], round(td[, col_rnm[i], with = FALSE], col_rd[i]))
}
```

If you look at the help page for `?set` (same help page as `?":="`), you'll see it described as

> `set` is a low-overhead loop-able version of `:=`

You'll find `set` used in many answers here, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28123372/903061) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249454/903061).

---

Reasons your approach didn't work:

- You're missing an `i` in your loop: `roundCols(td,col_rnm,col_rd[i])` needs to use `col_rnm[i]`
- Your `roundCols` function neither updates the data by reference using `data.table` syntax (either `set()` or `:=`), nor does it `return` the updated data, so any changes are local to the function
- The string `"namcol"` with quotes is just a string. To use the argument `namcol`, you need to use it without quotes.

You don't need an extra function for this---the approach above with `set` is simpler.