# multiple many columns by specific column using lists

Tags: r

I am basically working off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123098/multiply-many-columns-by-a-specific-other-column-in-r-with-data-table), but want to add one more wrinkle I can't figure out. I want to multiple all columns contained in a list by the weight column, similar to the example below:

```
#df 1
Id = c("1", "2", "3", "4")
Persons = c(300, 400, 200, 5000)
Houses = c(20, 40, 10, 23)
Ages =  c(45, 34, 50, 44)
Races = c(1, 3, 1, 2)
weight = c(0.9, 1.2, 0.8, 1.1)

estimates = data.frame(Id, Persons, Houses, Ages, Races, weight)
list <- as.list(colnames(subset(estimates, select = -c(Id, weight))))
estimates <- estimates %>% mutate_each(funs(.*weight), . %in% list)
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Error in `as_indices_impl()`: ! Must subset columns with a valid
> subscript vector. ✖ Subscript has the wrong type `logical`. ℹ It must
> be numeric or character.

Comment: Why would you put column names in a `list` instead of keeping them as a character vector?

Comment: The difference between a `list` and an atomic vector is that a `list` can contain elements of different classes - the first element can be a data frame, the second a numeric vector, the third a model object, and the fourth a character vector. Column names are character vector, there's no need to turn them into a `list` unless you're mixing them with other object types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the modern `across()` instead of the deprecated `mutate_each()`:

```
estimates %>% mutate(across(all_of(unlist(list)), \(x) x * weight))
```

Or with base R:

```
estimates[unlist(list)] <- estimates[unlist(list)] * estimate$weight
```

Of course, if you simplify your definition keeping it a character vector, then you can use `cols` instead of `unlist(list)`.

```
cols = setdiff(names(estimtes), c("Id", "weight"))
```

Or, with `across()` you can skip the `list` definition entirely:

```
estimates %>% mutate(across(!c(Id, weight), \(x) x * weight))
```